# Is it possible in a PyQt application to get access from JavaScript code to a new window, created with window.open() command?

Tags: javascript, pyqt, window.open, qwebengineview

I try to adapt a Web application to use in a GUI, created with PyQt6. When I load the application in `QWebEngineView` widget I'm capable to debug its JavaScript routines in a normal way using a Chrome browser launched in parallel.
The debugging shows that `window.open(...)` command in my JavaScript code goes without exceptions/errors and even creates a new window, having `window.opener` attribute among others.

I don't understand, however, is it possible to view the document of this new window in a certain other widget in my PyQt application and access its content from the main JavaScript code? Should I use `QTabWidget` or any other one for this?
Or I can control Web documents in other `QWebEngineView` widgets in my GUI with injected scripts only and forget about `window.open(...)` command?

Comment: The html/js documentation is of little use here, read that related to QWebEnginePage. For instance, [`createWindow()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwebenginepage.html#createWindow).

Comment: @musicamante, thanks for the suggestion! Indeed it is asserted in the documentation your link point to that "In the cases when the window creation is being triggered by JavaScript, apart from reimplementing this method the application must also set `QWebEngineSettings::JavascriptCanOpenWindows` to true in order for the method to get called". I will check how this might work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to. [The documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#return_value) states that `window.open` returns a [windowProxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/WindowProxy) object, so you *should* be able to use the returned object from that and traverse the DOM, execute scripts etc.

It would look something like this: `var newWindowObj = window.open(...)`, and then act on the `newWindowObj` however you need.

Comment: I already use exactly the same code: `const editableWindow = window.open(window.origin, "EditedPage"); window.myProjectData.editableWindow = editableWindow;`. Unfortunately it doesn't work this way, the stored `editableWindow` is empty. But even if we suggest for a moment the window is available I do not know how to put its content into a PyQt application GUI.